# How do I avoid "'zip' object is not reversible" errors when migrating to Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, migration

In my recently migrated from 2 to 3 Python code I have

```
list(reversed(zip(*positions)))
```

which generates the error

> TypeError: 'zip' object is not reversible

I can fix this by changing the problematic code to

```
list(reversed(list(zip(*positions))))
```

but this seems like the wrong way to go about it.

What is the correct way to revers a `zip` in Python 3?

Comment: no, it's okay, as `zip` doesn't return a `list` anymore. You cannot reverse any iterable until you've iterated on it fully

Comment: So this is the idiom? Why do I need the outer `list`: does `reversed(list(...))` not produce a `list` in 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reversed` is used to iterate on the list. It doesn't create a list on purpose, because it's often used just to iterate backwards on elements, not to create lists.

That's why you have to use `list` on it to create a `list`. And it *needs* a sequence to be able to get to the last element directly so you have to do `list(zip())` in python 3.

Maybe you could shorten

```
list(reversed(list(zip(*positions))))
```

to

```
list(zip(*positions))[::-1]
```

it creates a `list` directly without the need for `reverse` so it's probably slightly faster too.